# How to run different web apps on different port in same server?

Tags: php, apache, ports

I want to run different web app on different ports on same server, I have a apache php server running on a Linux machine. How can I achieve this ? and when I Google I stumble upon 'tomcat', what is this ? I am a noob, so please forgive if that is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache manual for the VirtualHost directive. It'll explain everything.

One thing to remember (it caught me out first time) - if you use virtual hosts, you have to define a virtual host for the default page too.

Don't worry about Tomcat at the moment. If you don't know what it is, you don't need it yet.

Answer (score -2):

**Step 1: Install the Tomcat files**

Download Tomcat 4.1 or 5.5, and unzip it into an appropriate directory. I usually put it in /usr/local, so it ends up in a directory called /usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.17 (5.5.17 being the current version as of this writing), and make a symlink named /usr/local/tomcat to that directory. When later versions come out, I can unzip them and relink, leaving the older version in case things don’t work out (which rarely if ever happens, but I’m paranoid).

**Step 2: Make directories for each instance**

For each instance of Tomcat you’re going to run, you’ll need a directory that will be CATALINA_BASE. For example, you might make them /var/tomcat/serverA and /var/tomcat/serverB.

In each of these directories you need the following subdirectories: conf, logs, temp, webapps, and work.

Put a server.xml and web.xml file in the conf directory. You can get these from the conf directory of the directory where you put the tomcat installation files, although of course you should tighten up your server.xml a bit.

The webapps directory is where you’ll put the web applications you want to run on the particular instance of Tomcat.

I like to have the Tomcat manager webapp installed on each instance, so I can play with the webapps, and see how many active sessions there are. See my instructions for configuring the Tomcat manager webapp.

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to install Tomcat (they don't actually know what it is), rather asking how to run multiple PHP apps (or web sites) on a single machine with different ports.